# View localhost site on iPhone on OSX

Tags: iphone, macos

I am building a .NET website with MonoDevelop on OSX Lion that is targeted for mobile devices.

On my desktop's browser, I am able to access the site via **http://127.0.0.1:8080**, but I would like to view it on my physical iPhone (I don't want to use the XCode simulator).

My iPhone and Mac are on the same network and I have enabled Web Sharing. I can actually get to the default Apache index.html (**http://192.168.1.104:80**) page, but I am not able to get to my site (**http://192.168.1.104:8080**).

I'm newer to the Mac and even less familiar with network management, so I hope I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: Is this the built-in Apache Server? Or a separate server running as part of the MonoDevelop package?

Comment: The pages I'm trying access are on the .NET server instance MonoDevelop creates, not Apache

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe websharing shares through port 80 (which is default port for http application ) or something like this.. Or check your firewall settings

Comment: WebSharing is sharing port 80, but that points to the apache server. I guess what I'm trying to do is simply access 8080, which is pointed to the MonoDevlop server.

Answer (score 0):

You may as well turn off web-sharing because web-sharing only operates the built-in Apache web-server.

What is happening is that the web-server that MonoDevelop is hosting your pages on has been set up to only allow connections coming from `localhost`. If this is the problem, entering in the lan IP of the OS X machine **on** the OS X machine will likely also not work (if the IP filtering work like it does on Apache).

You need to find the config files for the MonoDevelop server and allow access from addresses other than 127.0.0.1